# Microsoft Word Global Templates Loaded from SharePoint?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, templates

I have a Macro Enabled Template I use to store my Macros and I wanted to share them with my company without having to duplicate the document on everyone's computer or changing the file path in the macro coding to suite each computer in my company. Is it possible to put the Templated Document on Sharepoint and from that point have a shortcut placed on that person's computer to which they can load that template every time they start Microsoft Word from there?

Is there any caveats to this such as "needing to be connected to the internet at all times"? Or can they bypass this by having an offline version saved?

DISCLAIMER:
I would have tried this myself but I don't have those privileges available to me on my work computer unless I can show my company this is possible prior.

Any assistance would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted on Word Answers at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-word-global-templates-loaded-from/b26ef4ad-291e-4cd8-b68a-77e023de5f13

For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184